# To hide unused rows in Excel

Tags: ms-office, macos

How do I hide all unused rows in Excel? I hate that if I scroll to fast I do not stop at the end of the data.
I am running Excel 15.

Here is an example. I want every row after `263` hidden so when I scroll down the data scrolling stops at `263`. I also want every column after `E` hidden.

[image]

Comment: This is the ‘problem’  Numbers ‘solves’ with its canvas approach to tables of a finite size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Taken from [this](https://cdn1.tekrevue.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/20130601_excelmac_hidecells_2.jpg) article on TekReview***

Make sure to leave room for expansion, if necessary.

- Select the first column to the right of your data. Now we need to select all columns from this starting point to the end of the spreadsheet. Because Excel gives users spreadsheets with tens of thousands of rows and columns, we’ll use keyboard shortcuts to quickly jump to the end.
- With the rightmost empty column selected, press and hold the `Shift` key and then press `Command + Right Arrow`. This will jump you to the end of the spreadsheet while the `Shift` key automatically selects every cell in between.
- Now we have to tell Excel to hide these cells. With your cells still selected, go to Excel’s **Menu Bar** and choose `Format > Column > Hide`. You’ll now see all the cells to the right of your data disappear.
- Next, we need to deal with the cells below your data. Similar to the steps above, this time select the first row beneath your data. With the bottommost cell selected, press and hold `Shift` and then press `Command + Down Arrow`. This will jump you to the very bottom of the spreadsheet and select all the rows in between.
- Finally, head back up to Excel’s **Menu Bar** and choose `Format > Row > Hide`. You’re now left with a spreadsheet that features only cells containing your data, resulting in a much cleaner look.

[image]

If you need to expand your table, or simply don’t like the new look, you can easily unhide the cells. First, click the top-left heading cell that looks like a white arrow pointing to the bottom-right corner. Clicking this cell will select all cells in your spreadsheet, both hidden and not. Once selected, go to Excel’s **Menu Bar** and choose both `Format > Column > Unhide` and `Format > Row > Unhide`. Your spreadsheet will now be restored to the default look.

Comment: Obviously the above works but there is an additional option should you wish to expose some of the hidden rows: Edit > Go To… and enter a range from whatever rows you wish to see, e.g. A21:A30 — doesn't need to be the entire rows. This hidden range will be selected. Then Format > Row > Unhide, and the rows of the selected range will appear. Works for columns as well, and of course, you can do standard excel stuff like hide, or go to multiple ranges or named ranges.